# Transpose columns pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a DF like this:

| ID | Name | Mail | Phone1 | Phone2 | Mail1 | Mail2 | contact phone | contact mail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | info@iricresanluis.com.ar | 2664941642 | 2664941644 | info@iricresanluis.com.ar | info_tec@iricresanluis.com.ar | 115456789 | contact_mail@gmail.com |
| 71 | PEPSI | mail_general@pepsi.com | 0456535365 | 7766554399 | mail1@pepsi.com | mail2@pepsi.com | 8864545332 | last_mail@pepsi.com |

| ID | Name | LOCATOR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | info@iricresanluis.com.ar |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | 2664941642 |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | 2664941644 |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | info@iricresanluis.com.ar |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | info_tec@iricresanluis.com.ar |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | 115456789 |
| 70 | DASS ARGENTINA SRL | contact_mail@gmail.com |
| 71 | PEPSI | mail_general@pepsi.com |
| 71 | PEPSI | 0456535365 |
| 71 | PEPSI | 7766554399 |
| 71 | PEPSI | mail1@pepsi.com |
| 71 | PEPSI | mail2@pepsi.com |
| 71 | PEPSI | 8864545332 |
| 71 | PEPSI | last_mail@pepsi.com |

Is it possible to do anythong like this? I´ve tried with transpose function but I´m not getting the output like the example above

Comment: `df.melt(['ID', 'Name'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pd.melt to flatten the dataframe and then sort and remove the unwanted columns

```
df.drop(columns='ID').melt(id_vars='Name', value_name='Locator').sort_values('Name').drop(columns='variable')
```

```
                  Name  Locator
0   DASS ARGENTINA SRL  info@iricresanluis.com.ar
2   DASS ARGENTINA SRL  2664941642
4   DASS ARGENTINA SRL  2664941644
6   DASS ARGENTINA SRL  info@iricresanluis.com.ar
8   DASS ARGENTINA SRL  info_tec@iricresanluis.com.ar
10  DASS ARGENTINA SRL  115456789
12  DASS ARGENTINA SRL  contact_mail@gmail.com
1   PEPSI               mail_general@pepsi.com
3   PEPSI               456535365
5   PEPSI               7766554399
7   PEPSI               mail1@pepsi.com
9   PEPSI               mail2@pepsi.com
11  PEPSI               8864545332
13  PEPSI               last_mail@pepsi.com
```